# Facing problem while installing web3 for PyCharm

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, python

i recently tried to install web3 package to learn and develop blockchain technology in brief but when i tried to install the package via pip command it went well for the first few seconds and then errors started popping up it resolved to my visual C++ version issue. i updated my visual C++ package and then again tried to install web3 at this time i am getting this error and not reaching anywhere

error goes like :-

*Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict*

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before and there seems to be a lot of success with the answers posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Best of luck.

Comment: better suited as a comment rather than an answer